# Run as Full Screen a EXE File With Batch Script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

what i need to do?

i have a batch file converted to a exe file.

i found this code in this site.

```
start "" /MAX "cmd /K Test.bat"
```

it is simply useful to a batch file. bc using "start console as /max size"

but* i need to use it in the exe file with full screen.

so my goal is; i need to use "`CALL`" code to run a exe file with full screen.

you can suggest to download a library in this script to me,

Virtual Basic / C++ / Python / Lua or something, how much help me.

any engineer right there?

Comment: Might not be what you're trying to do bust just in case: Windows has a kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this command line with success.

```
start /max HackEduca_Conecta.exe
```

"HackEduca_Conecta.exe" is the file name.

It's important to be considered that sometimes the EXE file is blocked to be used in full screen mode, but generally works.